# Using Jquery Mobile v1.4.2 with Google Maps v3

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to write some code to display google maps in satellite view inside of JQuery Mobile/HTML.  So far to no success, seems all the example code is out of date or not functioning.  What i'm looking for is displaying a google map satellite image, getting two X/Y coordinates from code (these will actually be coming from a MySQL database query), and placing a marker on the map at that location.  The code I have is below.  When I run the full website code I can navigate to the maps page and see the header and back button but the map is not displaying.

Note this is called when a button is pressed on the main page.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="map-page" data-url="map-page" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Maps</h1>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas">
            <!-- map loads here... -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#map-page", function() {
var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.061414, -83.226385);  // Default to Lockerly Arb when no geolocation support

if ( navigator.geolocation ) 
{
    function success(pos) 
    {
        // Location found, show map with these coordinates
        drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
    }
    function fail(error) 
    {
        drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // Failed to find location, show default map
    }

    // Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
} 
else 
{
    drawMap(defaultLatLng);  //No geolocation support, show default map
}

function drawMap(latlng) 
{
    var myOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

    // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: "Lockerly Arboretum!"
    });
}
});
```

CSS:

```
`//Google Maps CSS
#map-page, #map-canvas 
{
    width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; 
}`
```

Comment: Fixed code format issue above, should be displayed properly now for viewing and debug.

Comment: Try changing this --- $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#map-page", function() {  -- to this --- $("#map-page").on( "pageshow",  function() { --- or ---  $(document).on("pageshow", "#map-page", function( event ) {

Comment: Nope nothing there even with those two changes still no map, just header and back button showing.

Comment: check this example ---  http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/  --  change  maptype from ROADMAP to   ----   HYBRID  -- i beileve to get satellite view

Comment: What is CSS rule for head and body tags? Try with something like `html { height: 100% } body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }`. Your CSS rules for #map-page and #map-canvas have `'` around. Do you have it in your code or it is just typo here?

Comment: @Anto that is a mistake put up by Stack Overflow when I entered it as code.  Added the CSS rule for body and html, still no luck.

Comment: @Tasos That code doesn't work at all, even the example on there page is broken.  Just to try it though I took there code and edited it to have the up to date Jquery mobile reference and CSS reference and it shows nothing.